# Calling specific objects within a list in python?

Tags: python, list, oop

I've defined the following:

```
class SMSMessage(object):

  def __init__(self, hasBeenRead, messageText, fromNumber):
      self.hasBeenRead = hasBeenRead
      self.messageText = messageText
      self.fromNumber = fromNumber

hasBeenRead = "False"
fromNumber = "07189202003"
```

With the following functions:

```
def MarkAsRead(self):
    if hasBeenRead == "False":
        return hasBeenRead == "True"

def add_sms():
    sms1 = (hasBeenRead, messageText, fromNumber)
    return SMSStore.append(sms1)

def get_count():
    return len(SMSStore)

def get_message(i):
    for i in SMSStore:
    return messageText

def get_unread_messages(i):
    for i in SMSStore:
        if hasBeenRead == "False":
           return messageText
```

This is the Logic for the SMS simulation where a user is meant to send messages to a list (SMSStore[ ]) and then recall specific messages from the list:

```
userChoice = ""

while userChoice != "quit":
    userChoice = raw_input("What would you like to do - read/send/quit?")

    if userChoice == "read":
        unreadChoice = raw_input("Would you like to retrieve all unread messages or one of your own choice? - all unread/custom  ")

        if unreadChoice == "custom":
            messageNo = int(raw_input("Please enter which messsage number you want to read: "))
            print get_message(messageNo)
            print MarkAsRead(messageNo)


        elif unreadChoice == "all unread":
            print get_unread_messages(hasBeenRead)

        else:
            print "incorrect entry"

    elif userChoice == "send":
        messageText = raw_input('Please type in your message')
        add_sms()

        print SMSStore
```

My main issue is that I am able to send the (hasBeenRead, messageText, fromNumber) to SMSStore but when trying to read I can't seem to return the messagetext of the user selected messageNo. It always returns the messageText of the last item in the list. I'm still new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There are a bunch of things that don't make any sense here, I wonder if you are unfamiliar with OOP. For instance, your first snippet does nothing apart from defining global `hasBeenRead` and `fromNumber` variables; it doesn't create an instance or pass those values to anything. And elsewhere you don't refer to the attributes via the instance with `self.hasBeenRead` etc. (Also, you should really use booleans - `True` and `False` - not strings `"True"` and `"False"`).

Comment: Thanks for boolean tip. let me post the actual task question and you could possibly advise me on a better strategy or approach? As mentioned I am still a noob but trying my best :).

Comment: Create a class definition for an SMSMessage which has three variables: hasBeenRead, messageText, and fromNumber. ● The constructor should initialise the sender’s number. ● The constructor should also initialise hasBeenRead to false. ● Create a method in this class called MarkAsRead which should change hasBeenRead to true. ● Create a list called SMSStore to be used as the inbox. ● Then create the following methods:

Comment: ○ add_sms - which takes in the text and number from the received sms to make a new SMSMessage object. ○ get_count - returns the number of messages in the store. ○ get_message - returns the text of a message in the list. For this, allow the user to input an index i.e. GetMessage(i) returns the message stored at position i in the list. Once this has been done, hasBeenRead should now be true. ○ get_unread_messages - should return a list of all the messages which haven’t been read. ○ remove - removes a message in the SMSStore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the role of SMSStore, but this block of code looks suspicious to me:

```
def get_message(i):
    for i in SMSStore:
    return messageText
```

Why are you iterating the SMSStore but just to return messageText ? Would that be a missing Indent over there ?

Comment: sorry if the indents didn't copy correctly. SMSStore is a list which stores messages which are added to the list when the user selects send. I then need to be able to recall the messageText of the desired user input through that function.

Comment: Create a class definition for an SMSMessage which has three variables: hasBeenRead, messageText, and fromNumber.
● The constructor should initialise the sender’s number.
● The constructor should also initialise hasBeenRead to false.
● Create a method in this class called MarkAsRead which should change
hasBeenRead to true.
● Create a list called SMSStore to be used as the inbox.
● Then create the following methods:

Comment: ○ add_sms - which takes in the text and number from the received sms to
make a new SMSMessage object.
○ get_count - returns the number of messages in the store.
○ get_message - returns the text of a message in the list. For this, allow the
user to input an index i.e. GetMessage(i) returns the message stored at
position i in the list. Once this has been done, hasBeenRead should now
be true.
○ get_unread_messages - should return a list of all the messages which
haven’t been read.
○ remove - removes a message in the SMSStore.

Comment: i suppose the get_message should looks like this?

Comment: i suppose the get_message should looks like this? 

def get_message(i):
    return SMSStore[i][1]